# How to reference defer loaded script tag json file content from javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, browser, deferred, script-tag

I want the load of the JSON file is not disrupting the normal page load so even if the JSON is 5mb big, the app will still do other critical functions while this huge JSON will be loaded afterward.

The challenge comes in that since this JSON file is really loaded in defer script tag, how am I suppose to reference it inside my javascript? how can my javascript know about it if I just load the JSON file right before the end of the `</body>`?

Any thought or even good alternative to achieve this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load your JSON asynchronously and then fire an event! Like:

**yourScript.js** (*which is imported that contains the JSON*)

```
window.myJSON = {...A lot of JSON}
const event = new CustomEvent("myJson-loaded", {"myJson": window.myJSON})
document.dispatchEvent(event)
```

All your javascript can now work like this:

```
document.addEventListener("myJson-loaded", function(e) {
    // Prints contents of window.myJSON, you can also, access it via the global variable myJson.
    console.log(e.detail)
    /*========= All your JS code here ===========*/
});
```

And if your codebase is split across multiple script files, you can listen for that event in **each** script file!

Comment: this actually sounds really interesting!

Comment: strange thing though, seems this deferred javascript file is not waiting all the js file at least completely loaded.... is this a wrong `<script` attribute I should be using? thought?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, then yes `deferred` does not mean that it's the last request, it just loads in an async fashion. So the events makes that a seamless process because all it says when `myJson` is loaded **only then** run the following js code.